# Not able to get unique session for logged-in user in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have the below requirement:
I am using AEM 6.3 version. There is a third party application which uses a SOAP Client. The SOAP client has few methods which are needed to be implemented. For one of the methods I need to provide a session ID of the logged in AEM user (The session object should have some basic information about the logged in user, the expiry time etc.). I would need session ID on the author instance only. 
**The third party application needs AEM pages information from the AEM author instance.**
Unfortunately I am not able to get any unique session ID of the logged-in user. The session that I get is the repository/ JCR session which changes every time the page is refreshed. 
Also I thought I could use JsessionID, but I do not know how to obtain the JsessionID.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [User Manager](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/security/user/UserManager.html) to obtain an Authorizable object:

```
        Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
        UserManager userManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(UserManager.class);

        Authorizable auth = userManager.getAuthorizable(session.getUserID());
```

And then you should be able to obtain ID or the user path to identify your "session".

Comment: \hi, i have already tries to implement it in the way you mentioned, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Authorizable auth = userManager.getAuthorizable(session.getUserID()); This gives me "anonymous" user

Comment: Where are you getting the Request/ResourceResolver from? If I use the above code for example in a Custom Servlet, the Authorizable object gives me my logged user ('admin').